# Is the Sigma 18-200 F3.5-6.3 DC Macro compatible with full-frame Nikon DSLRs?

Tags: nikon, sigma, full-frame, nikon-d600

Is the Sigma 18-200 F3.5-6.3 DC Macro lens compatible with the full frame D610?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The **DC** designation on Sigma lenses means it's a DX lens. Their **DG** designation indicates an FX lens.  Nearly all zoom lenses that start with 16-18mm at the wide end are crop lenses. Full frame walkaround zooms more typically start at 24mm or 28mm. The Sigma 28-300 DG lens is probably what you're looking for.